# Native Base: What's the difference between <Input> and <Styled(Input)>

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have a Native Base `<Item>` in my React Native app with an `<Input>` inside of it. When I inspect the `<Input>`, I see the following:

[image]

If I add a style property to the `<Input>`, it gets applied to both the `<Input>` and the `<Styled(Input)>`. There are some differences between the default styles on each though, such as that there is padding on `<Input>` but not on `<Styled(Input)>`.

**What I Want To Know:** What is `<Styled(Input)>`? What's the difference between `<Input>` and `<Styled(Input)>`?

Comment: @Rob The reason I posted the image is that it's of the inspector, and that's the only place the <Styled(Input)> appears. If I had just stated that <Input> gets rendered as a <Styled(Input)> with an <Input> inside of it, it wouldn't have been as clear as if I'd actually shown it. Is there a way you would have done it differently, based on the guidelines in the link you shared?

Comment: Left click -> select text --> copy --> paste.